# nhibernate joinqueryover unrelated tables (same foreign key)

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Basically what i am trying to do is join two tables on foreign keys. I have this query:

```
        var result =
            _session.QueryOver(() => contentReferenceAlias)
                    .Inner.JoinAlias(() => contentReferenceAlias.ContentReference, () => contentLibrarySearchAlias.ContentReference)
                    .Where(() => contentReferenceAlias.ToLanguage.Id == languageId && contentReferenceAlias.ContentReference.Id == contentLibrarySearchAlias.ContentReference.Id)
                    .SelectList(list => list
                                            .Select(() => contentReferenceAlias.ContentReference)
                                            .Select(() => contentLibrarySearchAlias.ContentReference)
                                            .Select(() => contentReferenceAlias.ContentReference.Id).WithAlias(() => resultAlias.ContentReferenceId)
                                            .Select(() => contentReferenceAlias.ContentReference.Id).WithAlias(() => resultAlias.ContentReferenceId)
                                            .Select(() => contentReferenceAlias.OrderedFrom).WithAlia
```

The SQL im trying to recreate:

```
  SELECT A.OrderedFrom, C.LastOrdered, A.ContentReferenceId, B.Title FROM TranslationContentReference A
  INNER JOIN TranslationOrder C ON (A.TranslationOrderId = C.Id)
  INNER JOIN ContentLibrarySearch B ON (A.ContentReferenceId = b.ContentReferenceId)
  WHERE A.ToLanguageId = 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I do understand your scenario correctly, join over man-in-the-middle (foreign key reference) cannot be achieved via QueryOver API. NHibernate needs to know pathes all the way down, So if there is no explicit mapping from `TranslationContentReference` through `ContentReference` to `ContentLibrarySearch`, then we cannot create correct JoinAliases.

So, first option is to extend the man-in-the-middle object

```
public class ContentReference
{
    ...
    public virtual IList<TranslationContentReference> TranslationContentReference { get; set;}
    public virtual IList<ContentLibrarySearch> ContentLibrarySearch { get; set;}
}
```

Then we can navigate (create pathes)

- from `TranslationContentReference` to `ContentReference`
- from `ContentReference` to `ContentLibrarySearch`

The second option, which is less NHibernate and more SQL, is to create `ISQLQuery`

```
ISQLQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery(
  "SELECT A.OrderedFrom, C.LastOrdered, A.ContentReferenceId, B.Title 
    FROM TranslationContentReference A
     INNER JOIN TranslationOrder C ON (A.TranslationOrderId = C.Id)
     INNER JOIN ContentLibrarySearch B ON (A.ContentReferenceId = b.ContentReferenceId)
    WHERE A.ToLanguageId = :language");
query.SetString("language", "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx");
var result = query.SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(MyDTO)))
.List();
```

Comment: I went with the create SQL query option, was the quickest way to the target, since performance was the whole reason for doing this, it seemed like the best idea. Thanks for the answer, and for verifying that i was trying to do something "impossible".

Comment: Yeah, this is correct. A bit complicated SQL statement via NHibernate infrastructure (result transformer). So powerful ;)